# Is there a way to implement analog of Python's 'separator'.join() in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

All I've found is `boost::algorithm::string::join`.  However, it seems like overkill to use Boost only for join.  So maybe there are some time-tested recipes?

**UPDATE**:
Sorry, the question caption were bad.
I'm looking for method to concatenate strings with separator, not just to concatenate one-by-one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're looking for a *recipe*, go ahead and use the one from Boost. Once you get past all the genericity, it's not too complicated:

1. Allocate a place to store the result.
2. Add the first element of the sequence to the result.
3. While there are additional elements, append the separator and the next element to the result.
4. Return the result.

Here's a version that works on two iterators (as opposed to the Boost version, which operates on a *range*.

```
template <typename Iter>
std::string join(Iter begin, Iter end, std::string const& separator)
{
  std::ostringstream result;
  if (begin != end)
    result << *begin++;
  while (begin != end)
    result << separator << *begin++;
  return result.str();
}
```

Comment: Please consider that this version, while very versatile, is by far not the most performant. So if you will be doing many joins, you may want to avoid using ostringstream.

Comment: @smoothware what do you suggest as a more performant solution ?

Comment: @hannibal Not using streams, there is no need for them. I will make a performance test shortly.

Comment: @hannibal: So I just tried a trivial solution I thought would be faster (append to string the result of to_string), but it turns out it's roughly 2x slower, so I suppose I was wrong on that point, thanks ;) Since we do need the formatting, guess it's good to use the class which was made for it... Note, this is using ints. For concatenating specifically strings (without performing formatting), it is much faster to simply append!

Comment: Another point: consider iterating over all strings first and counting the total size to std::string::reserve() the result before concatenating everything (assuming you are concatenating string objects or string_views etc.

Comment: @Smoothware, note that iterating over all strings first requires that the iterator can be traversed multiple times.

Answer (score 14):

If you really want `''.join()`, you can use `std::copy` with an `std::ostream_iterator` to a `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
#include <iterator>  // for std::ostream_iterator
#include <sstream>   // for std::stringstream

std::vector<int> values(); // initialize these
std::stringstream buffer;
std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(buffer));
```

This will insert all the values to `buffer`. You can also specify a custom separator for `std::ostream_iterator` but this will get appended at the end (this is the significant difference to `join`). If you don't want a separator, this will do just what you want.

Answer (score 11):

simply, where the type in the container is an int:

```
std::string s = std::accumulate(++v.begin(), v.end(), std::to_string(v[0]),
                     [](const std::string& a, int b){
                           return a + ", " + std::to_string(b);
                     });
```

Answer (score 4):

This works with C++17:

```
template<class...T>
std::string join(const std::string& sep, T&&...strings) {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(T)) {
        auto t = ((strings + sep) + ...);
        return t.substr(0, t.size() - sep.size());    
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << join(",", "apple", "orange", "banana") << std::endl;
    std::cout << join(",") << std::endl;
}
```

It should print:

```
apple,orange,banana
```

Comment: Nice!! A slightly different approach would be: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat, see also https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/pull/270

Answer (score 1):

C++ strings are implemented efficiently.

```
std::string s = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

This could be faster:

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(total_size_to_concat);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
  str.append(s[i], s[i].length());
}
```

But this is basically what your compiler do with `operator+` and a minimum of optimization except it is guessing the size to reserve.
Don't be shy. Take a look at [the implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc?revision=170686&view=markup) of strings. :)

Comment: I would bet that for large amounts of strings it is much faster to use a `stringstream`.

Comment: @Space: Maybe in C++03. In C++0x I believe the moving stuff will make both similarly efficient.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't think so, because move semantics will not help to put all the data into one continuous block of memory.

Comment: @Space: In the final string, it will be, no?

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't know how they implemented it, but they usually know their stuff.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, using move-semantics you could save the last allocation (and copy). However, a `std::stringstream` is able to use an allocation-strategy similar to `std::vector`, thus saving a lot of allocations. At least, this is how I see it. I can be wrong. I don't have my head wrapped around move-semantics very much yet.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: check the link in my answer, basically they take one part, `insert` it into the other, and return the result.

Comment: See my comment at the accepted answer, for string objects, pure concatenation is much faster simply by avoiding the unneeded stream overhead. Also reserving the size upfront brings performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version that I find more handy to use:

```
std::string join(std::initializer_list<std::string> initList, const std::string& separator = "\\")
{
    std::string s;
    for(const auto& i : initList)
    {
        if(s.empty())
        {
            s = i;
        }
        else
        {
            s += separator + i;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

You can then call it this way:

```
join({"C:", "Program Files", "..."});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Qt in your project you can directly use the `join` function of QString ([QString Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join)) and it works as expected from python. Some examples:

```
QStringList strList;
qDebug() << strList.join(" and ");
```

Result: `""`

```
strList << "id = 1";
qDebug() << strList.join(" and ");
```

Result: `"id = 1"`

```
strList << "name = me";
qDebug() << strList.join(" and ");
```

Result: `"id = 1 and name = me"`

Answer (score 0):

Just another simple solution:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::string str_join(const std::string& delim, const T& items)
{
    std::string s;

    for (const auto& item : items) {
        if (!s.empty()) {
            s += delim;
        }
        s += item;
    }

    return s;
}
```

For those who don't like `begin()`, `end()` as arguments and prefer just the whole container. And for those who don't like string streams and prefer some `operator std::string() const` instead.

Usage:

```cpp
auto s1 = str_join(", ", std::vector<const char*>{"1","2","3"});

struct X
{
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return "X";
    }
};

auto s2 = str_join(":", std::vector<X>{{}, {}, {}});
```

Should work with C++11 and later.